# In Sublime text 3 how do I default a certain file to a specific type

Tags: sublimetext3

I'm working with Fastlane.tools and I want my `Fastfile` to always open with ruby syntax.  I'm not sure exactly where to change this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on the bottom right language selector, or go to **View > Syntax** then go to **Open all with current extension as...** and pick your desired language.

This will apply for all files of this extension.

Comment: Is there a way to match on filename not extension?